# Something is Leaving my Files Open

Tags: c#, pdf, model-view-controller

I have a web api that creates 2 temporary PDFs, merges them, then deletes them.  Problem is, in my code, when it goes to clean out the temp files, it tells me they're being used by another process.  Something in the below code is keeping the files open so that, after this function is called, they can't be deleted.  For the life of me, I can't figure out what.  I've tried disposing whatever resources I can find and deleting the files in all different places trying to figure out WHAT is leaving them open, and I think I've narrowed it down to the if statement after the f counter is being incremented.  I think it doesn't like the way the reader is being reassigned.

```
public static bool MergeFiles(string destinationFile, string[] sourceFiles)
{

    int f = 0;

    var reader = new PdfReader(sourceFiles[f]);

    int n = reader.NumberOfPages;

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        var document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);

        document.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

        while (f < sourceFiles.Length)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < n)
            {
                i++;
                document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i));
                document.NewPage();

                PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);

                int rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i);
                if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
                {
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0,reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
                }
                else
                {
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                }
            }

            f++;

            if (f < sourceFiles.Length)
            {
                reader = new PdfReader(sourceFiles[f]);
                n = reader.NumberOfPages;
            }
        }
        document.Close();
        writer.Dispose();
    }
    reader.Close();
    reader.Dispose();

    Log.Info(string.Format("Documents merged into: {0}", destinationFile));
    return true;

}
```

Later in the code, the files are being removed using the following command:

```
File.Delete(tempCoverLetterFile);
```

FWIW: I've found that, if you put this code above the `using` statement, it will delete the one file, no problem:

```
reader.Dispose();
File.Delete(sourceFiles[0]);
```

I also found that, if you add a `reader.Dispose()` in the `if` statement before you reassign the reader to the next pdf, it works.  But, the end pdf that gets merged is corrupted and won't open.

Answer (score 1):

Where you have if f < sourcefiles.length you open a new reader.  However, you havent closed the old.  This would leave you with open files.

I would expect before the new reader is opened you need to add reader.close and reader.dispose (this latter maybe optional)

Comment: Funny thing about that is, if I add a reader.Dispose (or close) in where you're suggesting, then it errors on document.Close() because it "cannot access a closed file."  I can comment out "document.Close()," but then the pdf that gets merged is damaged and can't be opened... which doesn't happen if you just let it bomb when trying to delete the files on its own.  So, if you don't put in the reader.Dispose, it'll merge the PDFs, but won't delete the temps.  If you DO put in the reader.Dispose, it'll delete the temps, but won't merge them.

Comment: Hmm.  That just sounds odd.  Certainly not disbelieving, however, a reader.close, followed by reader = new pdfreader, should never produce a cant read..

Comment: Exactly. I think closing the reader is somehow closing the document, which makes it so that you can't edit it.  It's left hanging in limbo, and thus is corrupt and can't be opened.  I'm not sure why reader.close would close the document also.

Comment: Hmm, its possible because the original is used to define document.  While it would be the most insanely ugly code you ever saw.  Maybe rather than reusing reader, you want an array of reader, so you can open more, and then at the end close all of them.